how to present uint16 as float16
I have a buffer of float16 elements in the memory
I read this buffer to a list but since I use np.ctypeslib I can't read it as float16
so I read it as uint16 and now I want to represent it as float16
simple convert by list.astype(float16) won't help
I found this table https://gist.github.com/gregcotten/9911bda086c5850cb513b2980cca7648 and according to that table it works.
I want to write a python function for convention unint16_as_float16 but don't know what are the rules.
appreciate your help
thanks!

I think your question is already answered here uint16 to float16

@MartinBrown, the question you mentioned is for javascript. I need a pythonic way. (I edited the description)

I found a solution by numpy
uint16_list.view(np.float16)
